# Identifying the physical drive on a dell PowerEdge R320

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, dell, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

We have a PowerEdge R320 with four drives and the front indicator panel is saying there is a fault on 'Bay 1 Drive 2'. There is an orange indicator blinking on the third drive from the left. I'm trying to figure out if the orange indicator is the drive specified by the error on the fault display. If, for example, the drives (regardless of their bays) were numbered from 0 to 3, this would work to indicate that drive slot (if following a similar 0-x numbering scheme and broken into 2 drives each) was bay 1 (of 2: bay 0 and bay 1)

But i wanted to try to confirm which drive was which before we power down the server (which is active providing services on our network) to try to replace/recover the faulty drive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the drives are numbered from the left starting with 0. So the third drive with the orange light is Drive 2 and is the faulty drive.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to joeqwerty's answer: a server is likely to support hot plugging of disks in a RAID. Depending on the setup, it is quite possible that you can replace the disk without powering down.

Comment: Unfortunately, when attempting to do that on a Dell server, the RAID disk ID changed and the data was lost. This is not normal behavior.